# Template header not appearing in new C file when made in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

First, I did:

```
% vim ~/.vim/cvim/c-support/templates/Templates
```

From there, I changed my User Macros to their desired values.  I then saved my changes.

In Vim, I went to Normal Mode and entered:

```
:!vim test.c
```

However, my header created with User Macros did not appear at the top of the file.  I am using http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/tutorial-make-vim-as-your-cc-ide-using-cvim-plugin/ as a reference.

Also, here: https://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-c/csupport.html#csupport-templates, section 5.

I put the following into my `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:C_Styles = { '.c,.h' : 'C', '.cc,.cpp,.c++,.C,.hh,.h++,*.H' : 'CPP' }
```

However, this did not work, and my heading is not inserted into my newly created C source files.

I know this is a newbie question, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whatever it is, it is not about C. I'd actually say it is not about programming as set by the site-rules.

Comment: I am sorry, sir.  Could you please direct me to an appropriate place for this question?

Comment: [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would probably be a better forum to ask this.

Comment: Also, have a look at [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), a snippet engine for vim. You could use that to insert templates on the fly. But not just complete templates, all kinds of code fragments.

Comment: Hey just so you know posting the same question on multiple sites is [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) It's not the end of the world, but I would encourage you to delete one of these questions (the one here or the one on vi.se)

Comment: I would like to delete this one if possible.  Is there a way for it to be flagged?